# electric force of rubbing

Tags: electricity

When rubbing a ruler with my hair and get it closer to some pieces of papers , it'll attract them (they'll effect each other by an electric force). But why ? WhenI only charge the ruler not both of them ( I mean the pieces of papers too)

Comment: you will get your answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63557/why-does-the-comb-attract-the-pieces-of-papers-if-theyre-neutral

Comment: Thank you so much